# Wireframe artifact shows up when rendering close-up detail in Blender 3.0

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, artifacts, wireframe

I have a wireframe problem.

When I render close-up detail image, wireframe wrongly show up on the surface of the model. I`ve set the model in smooth mode and subdivision level is high enough and everything shows correct in viewport.

It only shows up when rendering no matter rendering in viewport or hit F12, no matter use GPU or CPU Cycles.

The following image is in viewport shading mode/ viewport rendering mode/ cycles CPU/ Cycles GPU.

[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Is there any setting I missed?

Comment: Hi :) Just a guess. Could there be two identical models se to render only?

Comment: If you're using a _subdivision surface_ modifier, there are 2 settings for subdivision levels - one for the viewport and another for the render - are they both set to the same level?

Comment: Hi, @Jachym, glad to get comment. I`ve double-checked the model, it is one single model for sure.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherBennett , thanks to reply. I`ve  set viewport to 1 and render parameter to 2. And what`s more weird is, not matter how high I set these number, it  always render this wireframe artifact just need camera to get close enough to render and the artifact shows more intensive no matter in viewport or in render window. But if I replace a new material without any texture, the render outcome will be correct.

Comment: Hmmm. On closer inspection, those look like they might be caused by Subsurface Scattering. Make sure to keep the level below .3 or .4 (max) and use "Random Walk" instead of "Christensen Burley"

Comment: That`s it! Thank a lot! @ChristopherBennett problem solved perfectly! Reason is I used "random walk(Fixed radius)" mode. Wireframe disappeared after I transfer to  "random  walk". But Im still curious about why it happened though.