# Cycles causing visible triangulated wireframe over mesh?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, artifacts, wireframe

I can't seem to solve this issue (see render)
[image]

As you can see, there's a faint wireframe being rendered on top of my mesh. Occurs in cycles viewport and render. Any tips on how to solve other than starting fresh? There are no wireframe modifiers present anywhere in my scene. even adding a fresh Suzanne Monkey to the project seems to reflect the same issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe try the solution in the comments here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252912/wireframe-artifact-shows-up-when-rendering-close-up-detail-in-blender-3-0 (Switch Subsurface Scattering to "Random Walk" and keep it below .4)

Comment: Hmm.. There's no subsurface scattering anywhere in my scene.

Comment: You might wanna share your file so people can take a look then. Just the Suzanne, for ex. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: copy that, just added the file. The artifacts seem to be very lighting dependent - for me they're very visible under the "moonlit golf" preset hdri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be caused by your model's distance to the origin. Too much disparity between your model's smallest and biggest dimensions can engender all kinds of rendering issues, from clipping, to Z-fighting, to... this:

[image]

Comment: aha! thanks for the info.